# React Native "Invalid Hook"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, color-scheme

I don't understand how I can put the colorScheme const inside the config const.
I'm getting the error: "Invalid Hook call"

```
import {extendTheme} from 'native-base'
import { useColorScheme } from 'react-native';

const colorScheme = useColorScheme()
const config = {
    
    useSystemColorMode: false,
    initialColorMode: colorScheme
}

const colors={
    primary:{
        50: '#EEF2F6',
        100: '#CFD9E7',
        200: '#B1C1D8',
        300: '#92A9C9',
        400: '#7491B9',
        500: '#5578AA',
        600: '#446088',
        700: '#334866',
        800: '#223044',
        900: '#111822'
    }
}
export default extendTheme({config,colors})
```

Comment: what is colorScheme? is it a method returning an object, or is it just an object? You could maybe just do `initialColorMode: colorScheme`

Comment: It is not specified if it is a method: https://reactnative.dev/docs/usecolorscheme

Comment: It is specified, that it returns a 'color scheme' which is ```light, dark, null```, https://reactnative.dev/docs/usecolorscheme#supported-color-schemes

Answer (score 1):

Your hook can only be used inside a component, like so;

```
const MyComponent = () => {

    const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

    const config = {
        useSystemColorMode: false,
        initialColorMode: colorScheme
    }

    return (
        <>...</>
    )    
}
```

Comment: It keep giving me this errror: "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. "

Comment: updated answer to represent whole component. You were probably calling your hook outside your component

Comment: I have updated my code to explain better what i need

Comment: You need to do this inside the component, without that you can not use useColorScheme hook.